# Adding a dynamic tr and referencing it with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have a table and when a user clicks on one of the table rows, I want it to add a row right after the row that was clicked on. After it's done adding, I want to populate the row with some ajax info. In this ajax info that's being passed will be a button to 'close/destroy' the row. How do I acheive this? I've tried this so far and it doesn't work.

```
  <tr onclick="$(this).append('<tr style=\'background-color:#ff0000;\'><td colspan='5'>AJAX CONTENT GOES HERE</td></tr>');">
    <td class="center"><%=location%></td>
    <td><span class="text-warning"><%=formatcurrency(refundAmount,2)%></span> <small class="muted">(potential)</small></td>
    <td><span class="text-error"><%=formatcurrency(refundReceived,2)%></span></td>
    <td><span class="text-info"><%=formatcurrency(lateAmount,2)%></span></td>
    <td><span class="text-success"><%=formatcurrency(refundReceived+refundAmount,2)%></span> <small class="muted">(potential)</small></td>
  </tr>
```

It'd be even better if I could put this in a function. I'd also like to slide that row in and out. Thanks guys, I appreciate all comments!

damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on tymeJV's answer above, but including the button to destroy the row if the user so chooses:

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
    var htmlRowData = "<tr style=\'background-color:#ff0000;\'><td>";
    $.ajax() {
        //do some ajax stuff here
        success: function(data) {
            htmlRowData += data;
        }
    });
    var removeRow = function(this){
        $(this).parents("td").remove();
    }
    htmlRowData += "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this)'";
    htmlRowData += "</td></tr>";
    $(this).after(htmlRowData).slideDown(); <-- Append and achieve sliding effect
});
```

Comment: I did something very similar to that. It seems like the ajax is too slow and the code executes b4 the ajax call is finished. I tried putting the $(this).after into the successfull ajax call function but no go. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the .done() callback is where you want to put it. Check out the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about 11/12 of the way down the page.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to handle the OnClick event in every cell, second, it could be better if you abstract this into a function, more less like this:

```
function addRow(element)
{
    $(element).append('<tr style=\'background-color:#ff0000;\'><td colspan='5'>AJAX CONTENT GOES HERE</td></tr>');
}
```

Then, add an Id to your table so you can reference it easily, assuming you give it a "MyTable" id, then you can do this:

```
onClick = "addRow('#MyTable')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve it with something like this:

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
    var htmlRowData = "<tr style=\'background-color:#ff0000;\'><td>";
    $.ajax() {
        //do some ajax stuff here
        success: function(data) {
            htmlRowData += data;
        }
    });
    htmlRowData += "</td></tr>";
    $(this).after(htmlRowData).slideDown(); <-- Append and achieve sliding effect
});
```

Comment: won't this make the newly created "tr" also clickable by the

`$('table tr").click

Comment: No, the newly tr isn't there at run-time, therefore the click handler won't be assigned to dynamic content.

Comment: I tried this and i can't get it to work. What seems to be going on is the ajax is too slow to update the htmlRowData with the ajax info. I've tried putting the $(this).after inside the success function of the ajax call but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?     $(function(){

     $("table tr").click(function() {
      var htmlRowData = "<tr><td colspan=5 style='padding:20px;'>";
      $.get('/admin/ajax/report_users.asp',function(data){
       htmlRowData+=data+'</td></tr>';
      });

      $(this).after(htmlRowData).slideDown();

     });
    });

Comment: Well normally you would add a timer to wait for the ajax call to finish...the quick fix is to add `async: false,` to your ajax markup :).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){
$var =
'\
<tr>\
    <td>asdf</td>\
    <td><input type="button" value="I need an event handler"></td>\
</tr>\
';
$(this).parent().append($var);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M3BpW/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr:not(".closeDestroy")').on('click', function(){
        var activeTr = $(this);
        if(activeTr.next('tr').hasClass('closeDestroy')) return false;
        $.post('your_url', function(data) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>', {'class':'closeDestroy', 'style':'background-color:#ff0000'});
            var td = $('<td/>', {'html':'<button>Destroy</button>', 'colspan':5});
            activeTr.after(tr.append(td));
        });
    });

    // Click handler for button
    $('table').on('click', 'tr.closeDestroy td button', function(){
        // code for clicked button
        var button = $(this);
        button.closest('tr').prev().remove().andSelf().remove();
    });
});
```

Just change the content of `td` variable to use data from your ajax call, for example, if you have an id to use in the button then you can use

```
var td = $('<td/>', {'html':'<button id='+data.id+'>Destroy Me</button>', 'colspan':5});
```

Also try to use an `id` in your table to use `$('table#myId tr:not(".closeDestroy")')` to make the the selection more specific.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/UTBME/3/)